# Changing multi select element with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

There is a multi select element in my page.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <select ng-show="'@Model.IsWinnerFilterVisible'" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Kazanan" ng-model="MainWinnerFilterSelected" id="ddl_winnerid"
                            data-ng-options="MainWinnerFilter.Id as MainWinnerFilter.Name for MainWinnerFilter in MainWinnerFilters"></select>
                </div>
 <div class="form-group">
                    <select ng-show="'@Model.IsReasonFilterVisible'" class="form-control" title="İlgilenilmeme Nedeni" ng-model="MainReasonFilterSelected" id="ddl_reasonid" ng-init="MainReasonFilterSelected= @Model.SelectedReason"
                            data-ng-options="MainReasonFilter.Id as MainReasonFilter.Name for MainReasonFilter in MainReasonFilters">
                        <option value="">İlgilenilmeme Nedeni</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

And i can load this first with the code below

```
 $scope.MainWinnerFilterSelected = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SelectedWinner));
```

I want to reload this element with a new data but it dosent work.

```
 $scope.loadReasonAndWinner= function() {
        var productGroupFilters=$scope.productGroupFilterSelected;
        var res = $http.post('@Url.Action("GetWinnerAndReasonList", "Details")', {'selectedProductGroup':productGroupFilters});
        res.success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.MainWinnerFilters=data.WinnerList;
            $scope.MainReasonFilters=data.NotInterestingReasonList;
        });
        res.error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.addError("alert-danger","Bir Hata oluştu.","Error");
        });

    }
```

In controller;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetWinnerAndReasonList(int SelectedProductGroup)
    {
        var detail = new DetailsModel();
        detail.SelectedProductGroup = SelectedProductGroup;
        var winnerList = BiddingService.RetrieveWinners(null, VariableHelper.ListOf(detail.SelectedProductGroup));
        detail.WinnerList = BiddingService.TranslateToFilter(winnerList);

        var notInterestedActionStatus = new List<int>() { VariableHelper.Int(ActionStates.NotInterested) };
        var notInterestingReasonList = BiddingService.RetrieveActionReason(notInterestedActionStatus, VariableHelper.ListOf(detail.SelectedProductGroup));
        detail.NotInterestingReasonList = BiddingService.TranslateToFilter(notInterestingReasonList);

        return Json(detail);
    }
```

New data comes true and it works with combobox (MainReasonFilter) but it dosent change the items in multiselect element(MainWinnerFilter). Any idea with that?

Comment: Mhm, please add your full view where your controller is beinded and please add your full controller.

Comment: Full view and full controller may be 
complicated ,there are so many things in there. But i can say that the problem is about multiselect. Codes work with combobox(MainReasonFilters). But i change it as multi select 
it dosent work.